# Can a Lambda Authorizer be used in AWS API Gateway to prevent public access to an API's /swagger documentation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I've been reading about Lambda Authorizers in AWS API Gateway and have a strong suspicion that they would be perfect for locking down access to see the swagger UI pages for lambda based REST microservices (Most implemented in aspnetcore, .net 6, swagger provided by Swashbuckle, deployed with SAM, fronted with API Gateway), but I'm having trouble finding a sample.

I'd like to know if someone has done something similar where a Lambda Authorizer is attached to a specific wildcarded route (ex: GET /swagger/*) protecting everything under it. Ideally unauthorized access (missing the JWT access token in the Authorization: Bearer header) would redirect to our OAuth login page and require a specific role on the JWT Access token before Swagger UI even appears.